# Why is su disabled from guest sessions?

Tags: security, guest-session, su

From guest you can't `sudo` or `ssh`. Why I can't `sudo` is simple. But why can't I `su`?

What is it that `su` provides that `ssh` to the user@localhost wont?

The reason for this question being my [other question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/927937?noredirect=1) which has attracted a lot of criticisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be for security reasons, so a guest won't be able to  somehow "hack" the system and gain administrator rights, making changes which will break the OS.

What if a "guest" knows some kind of security hole and somehow logs in without knowing the password of root or another privileged user and log in using su? Then he/she may even run a `rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` and ruin the whole system!

Comment: I know that, but can you be specific?

Comment: @daltonfury42 if a "guest" knows some kind of security hole and somehow logs in without knowing the password of `root` or another privileged user and log in using `su`? Then he/she may even run a `rm -rf --no-preserve-root /`...

Comment: Yes, that's a possiblity. Privilege Escalation. Add that to your answer and I will accept it.