# How is the guest account prevented from using su and sudo?

Tags: sudo, security, guest-session, apparmor, su

It's already known that the guest account can't use `su` or `sudo`:

- [Why is su disabled from guest sessions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/646949/158442)
- [Sudo not available in guest login](https://askubuntu.com/q/362528/158442)

*How* is this done?

My guess would be apparmor. However, there's no mention of either in `/etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session` (or other files included in it).

Is it done by denying some capability?

```
$ grep cap /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm
  capability ipc_lock,
  deny capability dac_override,
  deny capability dac_read_search,
```

`dac_override` seems to be a good candidate. According to [`man capabilities`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/capabilities.7.html):

```
CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE
      Bypass file read, write, and execute permission checks.  (DAC is
      an abbreviation of "discretionary access control".)

CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH
      * Bypass  file  read  permission  checks  and directory read and
        execute permission checks;
      * Invoke open_by_handle_at(2).
```

Is this it, or is it some other capability? Or is it not apparmor at all?

---

Apparently, it's the `setgid` capability. From `syslog` for a `su` attempt:

```
Mar 18 12:14:52 muru-wily kernel: [ 5285.025017] audit: type=1400 audit(1458283492.316:159): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=25687 comm="su" capability=6  capname="setgid"
```

However:

```
$ sudo grep setgid /etc/apparmor* -R
/etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.sbin.rsyslogd:  capability setgid,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.tcpdump:  capability setgid,
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/.features:caps {mask {chown dac_override dac_read_search fowner fsetid kill setgid setuid setpcap linux_immutable net_bind_service net_broadcast net_admin net_raw ipc_lock ipc_owner sys_module sys_rawio sys_chroot sys_ptrace sys_pacct sys_admin sys_boot sys_nice sys_resource sys_time sys_tty_config mknod lease audit_write audit_control setfcap mac_override mac_admin syslog wake_alarm block_suspend audit_read
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd:  capability setgid,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.cupsd:  capability setgid,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.rsyslogd:  capability setgid,
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser:    capability setgid,     # for sandbox to drop privileges
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dovecot-common:  capability setgid,
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/postfix-common:  capability            setgid,
```

Aside from the `.cache` folder, nothing seems to be restricting `setgid`. However, [`man apparmor.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/apparmor.d.5.html) says:

```
Capabilities
   The only capabilities a confined process may use may be enumerated;
```

If I understand correctly, then if any capabilities are listed, then only those can be used - all others are restricted. Does the `capability ipc_lock` line automatically restrict all other unmentioned capabilities? If so, why `deny capability dac_override` and `deny capability dac_read_search`?

Comment: Well . . . Its not in sudo group for one

Comment: @Serg can't be that. The error message is `setgid: operation not permitted`. If it were in `sudoers`, you would get a nice error from `sudo`, and it wouldn't affect `su`.

Comment: I suspected PAM, but as of now found no evidence of that (`grep -r 'guest' /etc/pam.d` reports nothing), however how is the guest user even called? I don't seem to even have a guest user in Ubuntu GNOME 15.10.

Comment: @kos Maybe GDM doesn't have a guest option. LightDM does.

Comment: As regards why, it would [defeat the purpose](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html) with a **restricted** session.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I don't care about the why. Already asked and answered enough times.

Answer (score 0):

From doing a quick search, I think the answer is that Ubuntu does not actually have a guest account, it uses a "guest session".  Guest sessions cannot make any real changes to a system, so if you log on and try to save a file to the sessions home directory, when you log out, those files are removed.

You can almost think of a guest session as a live USB/CD session.

Most of my searches on guest session only give me options to remove it, I did find one that talked about creating a guest user, and that is different from the guest session.

Comment: The "guest session" does, in fact, create an account and group (`guest-<randomstring>`, usually) for the session (you can see them in `/etc/{passwd,group}` when somebody's logged in as a guest). But call it what you will, this still doesn't tell me how it's prevented from using `sudo` or `su`.

Comment: I agree with you, it does not explain why exactly, but like you just said it creates an account of guest-<randomstring> once you close out does that account stay, or is it deleted? I believe it is deleted.   Ubuntu does not explain it any better than this... https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html  I am not sure how they did it, but they restricted the "guest session" in a way that will not allow a hacker to start a guest session and use the root account once in.

Comment: I have been doing searches now for over an hour, however they did this I am not sure, but I do now know this is a combination of lightDM, and AppArmor configuration. from following link after link, it leads me to know the issue is how AppArmor is sandboxing the guest session.  Can you try doing this from the terminal in the guest session su <YourUsername> I read in one of the posts that this might work.

Comment: Nope setgid: operation not permited when I tried it.

Comment: I search and search, and there is nothing on how they did this, but you were right it is AppArmor that sandboxes the guest session.