# Accidentally disabled the monitor, how can I reverse this?

Tags: display, xrandr

I was playing around with Ubuntu 16.04's display features and I accidentally turned off my monitor.

I can still see my screen on the login screen, but my screen disappears the second I log in to my user account. The system guest account is not affected.

Is there any way I can undo this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know your account password, this is going to be (thankfully) easy to fix.

1. Press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keys on your keyboard all at the same time. You will be transported to a TTY (or a giant terminal without any fancy graphics).
2. Log in to your user account. Note that you must know your username and password.
3. Delete the monitor config file:

   ```
   rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
   ```
4. Log out of the tty with the `logout` or `exit` command, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the GUI.
5. Log in as normal, and enjoy having your screen back.

The `monitors.xml` file contains practically all information about your own monitor configuration. Unfortunately, this gets annoying. And, as this file is owned by your user, you must either *be* your user or root.

If for some reason you can't reach the TTY, you'll need to reboot into [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/208574). Follow the instructions in that post until you see `root@something:~#`. Then, run this command:

```
rm /home/<your_username>/.config/monitors.xml
```

Then, reboot your system using the `reboot` command.

Comment: Isn't the guest account barred from using `sudo` and `su`? http://askubuntu.com/questions/747343/how-is-the-guest-account-prevented-from-using-su-and-sudo

Comment: @muru Huh, did not know that. I'll edit that out of my answer and go test. Be back in a moment.

Comment: step2 fails as after entering the password i see `setgid: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @Baig Yeah, my apologies about that. Muru pointed out an inconsistency inasmuch as the guest user can't use `su`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @KazWolfe thank you so much :) so happy to see the screen again.

Comment: This did work perfectly on Ubuntu 22.04 with Budgie when external monitors did work but the integrated display would simply turn black after log in. Also, I was not able to enable the integrated display in the Ubuntu settings, so this operation was a complete success :)