# Permission errors even when running docker containers using --cap-add or --security-opt

Tags: permissions, docker, apparmor

I'm trying to set the system time inside from a docker container¹.

I thought that to achieve this I'd simply have to add the capability `SYS_TIME`:

```
$ docker run --cap-add SYS_TIME -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
root@50007999ec5e:/# date --set "+2 hours"
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Thu Jan 1 2:00:00 UTC 1970
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Searching for similar errors I found suggestions that it might be AppArmor that is blocking the system call, so I tried adding `--security-opt apparmor:unconfined`, but, alas, without success:

```
$ docker run --security-opt apparmor:unconfined --cap-add SYS_TIME -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
root@c4d923009bab:/# date --set "+2 hours"
date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted
Thu Jan 1 2:00:00 UTC 1970
```

Which should mean that AppArmor is not at fault here.

Obviously running the container using `--privileged` works:

```
$ docker run --privileged -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
root@35ef33342149:/# date --set "+2 hours"
Thu Jan 1 2:00:00 UTC 1970
```

But the whole point of what I am trying to do is to experiment with docker security options and capabilities. Am I missing something here?
Can you suggest how to debug and fix this issue?

---

¹ Yes. I do know that system time is not a namespaced resource.

Comment: If AppArmor blocked something, it would show up in the logs

Comment: @muru Actually it would work when specifying `--security-opt apparmor:unconfined` also. That's why I'm puzzle and I am asking here...

Comment: @muru Also: which logs? There is no `apparmor.log` under `/var/log/`. `kern.log` only says that it started AppArmor.

Comment: syslog. You'll see entries like in https://askubuntu.com/q/747343/158442